# Is it valid to conduct a two sample t-test in this situation?

Tags: anova, t-test, mean

I know this is a real easy question, but I'm a little unsecure based on all that I read.
I have a dataset with housing prices across a city. One of the variables also stores the postal-code.
Now what I wanted to do was to first just do some box-plots. And in case I see any larger differences between two postal-code areas I thought about doing a two-sampled t-test between those two. My Ho would be that the means are equal.
My concerns are that there are some assumptions like the independence of the groups. So I just wanted to ask if this is a valid procedure to do. Or would something like this tukey-test or a anova would be more helpful in this case?

Answer (score 2):

Housing prices seem unlikely to be normally distributed so a two-sample Wilcoxon (rank sum) test might be a better choice than a t test. Even
with two distributions of different shapes the Wilcoxon test might
show that housing prices in one part of the city are generally larger
than in another (stochastic dominance).

Moreover, even if housing prices are roughly normal, it seems unlikely that variances of housing prices
would be equal in two parts of the city. so a Welch t test would be a
better choice than a pooled t test.

Depending on your purposes, side by side boxplots for the two parts of
the city might give a clear impression of what you want to show.

*Example* using simulated non-normal data: Houses in the hills tend to cost more than houses in the flatlands (Prices in hundreds of thousands of dollars.)

A two-sample Wilcoxon test confirms this (with P-value very nearly $0.)$ Boxplots (left in figure) may be sufficient to illustrate the differences. The empirical CDF plots (right panel) show that prices
in the hills tend to dominate (ECDF plot to the right).

```
set.seed(2020)
flat = rgamma(100, 5, .01)
hill = rgamma(100, 4, .005)   
wilcox.test(flat, hill)

        Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction

data:  flat and hill
W = 2967, p-value = 6.828e-07
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

[image]

R code for figure:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
 boxplot(flat, hill, names=c("Flat","Hill"), 
         col=c("tan","skyblue2"))
 plot(ecdf(hill), col="blue", main="")
  lines(ecdf(flat), col="brown")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot!! Just one question: Although I do have multiple (more than 2) postal-code areas (which would indicate doing an anova), I can select two areas and continue if I'd have only two groups?

Comment: For more than two areas: Perhaps nonparametric Kruskal-Wallis test `kruskal.test`, if data not normal. In R, perhaps `oneway.test` if normal with unequal variances. Of course, you could show more than two boxplots or ECDF plots.

Comment: @BruceET Why do you care how the housing prices are distributed? This is not relevant for the t-test.

Comment: @user2974951. Bad idea to use t tests for non-normal data--even if you've heard the (completely bogus) myth that anything goes for $n > 30.$

Comment: @BruceET What I've heard is that the means of the populations need to be normally distributed, not the data. And thanks to the CLT this will be true in a lot of cases, regardless of the distribution of the data. Of course outliers and ugly shapes will make it worse.

Comment: Well, the idea that only the mean in the numerator of the t statistic matters is not correct. In order for t-statistic to have a t distribution you need for the numerator (mean) and denominator (SD) to be independent, and that's only true for normal data. // You're correct that if you have far outliers or skewness (as for data in my Answ) the t test is so bad that it's often instantly recognizable as bad choice.

Comment: I had forgetten the mean and sd are only independent for the normal distribution. Is there a name for this phenomenon? Presumably for a given $n$, a binary distribution (as an example non-normal distribution) with mean close to $0.5$ has a mean and sd less dependent than if the mean is close to zero or one?

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely not valid, this is a clear case of multiple comparisons. You need to estimate a mean between all groups if you want to compare specific ones, such as with ANOVA / Tukey.

Regarding independence, I think you can forget about it. Unless you suspect that the houses are somehow related either within a group or between the groups. For ex. if the different postal codes contain specific types of houses (built by the same construction company, owned by the same owner, ...).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Helped to clarify things. If I'd have only the housing prices from two postal code areas however, I could do a t-test, right?

Comment: @robk Yes... but you dont have only two codes. Also, as mentioned in the other answer, make sure all the assumptions of the test are met before you apply it.